# How to use group by function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

Below is the my base table

[image]

I need to create view like below format based on my base table.
Here Deposit_Acc_Count is combination of (Type -> SB,RD, FD) and Loan_Acc_Count is (Type ->LO) same as for amount.

[image]

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation while grouping by `br_code` and `cif` columns such as

```
SELECT br_code, cif,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type IN ('SB','RD', 'FD') THEN Amt END) AS deposit_acc_count, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('SB','RD', 'FD') THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS deposit_acc_amt, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'LO' THEN Amt END) AS loan_acc_count, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'LO' THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS loan_acc_amt, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_count,
       SUM(amt) AS total_amt                   
  FROM t
 GROUP BY br_code, cif
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=beffd38726318ae312ed256b51f9489b)</kbd>